# Git: assign version number to git submodule

Tags: git

How do you assign a version number to git submodule?
When using `git submodule` to list my submodules, I see a version number printed after some of the submodules like this:

```
2ac913c37058b9bd49f87953a7968a4aa9705f47 PAPreferences (0.4)
```

How to configure my git repository so that my repository can also show a version number when being used as a submodule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [tag](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag). You can confirm this by observing that the PAPreferences repository currently has [four tags](https://github.com/dhennessy/PAPreferences/tags), including `0.4` on revision `2ac913c`.

To tag your own repository, run `git tag -a <tag> <commit>`. In the above case, `<tag>` would have been `0.4` and `<commit>` would have been `2ac913c`, or possibly the name of a branch whose tip pointed at `2ac913c` at the time the tag was created. You can omit `<commit>` if you simply want to tag `HEAD`.

You will be prompted for a commit message.

Like most things in Git, your new tag is local until you push it. To push tags, after your normal push you should run `git push --tags`.